# Properties of a function that is everywhere continuous and increasing

Tags: calculus

> If $f$ is a function that is everywhere continuous and increasing,
>   which of the following statements must be true?
>
> A. The inverse of $f$ is also a function.
>
> B. The inverse of $f$ is everywhere decreasing.
>
> C. $f$ is everywhere differentible.
>
> D. $f^{-1}$ and $f$ are the same function.
>
> E. $\dfrac{1}{f}$ and $f^{-1}$ have the same graph.

This is my attempt, I just need to make sure if I am understanding this correctly:

A. Not always, the function must be a one to one function.

B. I would assume it is, if the original function is increasing, the inverse would be the opposite and I assume it would be decreasing. (I am not sure about this.)

C. Not true.

As for D and E, I am not quite sure about them.. I would appreciate some help..

Comment: What do you mean by "increasing"?  Do you mean $a>b \implies f(a)>f(b)$?  If so then Hint:  show that increasing implies one-to-one.

Comment: Beyond that...examples are always useful.  Try $f(x)=x$.  That's continuous and increasing.  Then try $f(x)=3x$ or $f(x)=3x+1$. How do the various questions play out with these examples?